# PHPGD imagem sobre a outra, enviar para trás

Tags: php

Estou colocando um quadro e inserindo o fundo, porem a imagem fica por cima. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de enviar para trás, tipo o que os editores gráficos fazem, já tentei inverter o código, inserido primeiro o fundo e depois o quadro, porem a imagem só fica com o tamanho do fundo.

Resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria ficar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```
$imagem = imageCreateFromPng('imgs/quadro.png');

  imageAlphaBlending($imagem, true);
  imageSaveAlpha($imagem, true);


$fundo = imageCreateFromPng('imgs/bg.png');
  imageAlphaBlending($fundo, true);
  imageSaveAlpha($fundo, true);



imagecopy($imagem, $fundo, 60, 30, 0, 0, imagesx($fundo), imagesy($fundo) );


 header('Content-type: image/png');
  imagepng($imagem);
```

Comment: tem que inverter mesmo, senao vai ficar por cima. o tamanho da imagem você escolhe no imagesx() e imagesy(), se quer da frente ou do fundo. E como você está pondo margem, tem que inverter as origens também, senão corta.

Comment: Mas eu colocando as margens 0, ainda não ta certo, fica cortado

Comment: imagecopy($fundo, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($imagem), imagesy($imagem) );

Comment: veja como fica https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/800/030/original/download_%281%29.png?1483017342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de sobrepor as imagens, crie uma base. Assim:

```
 #Imagem base com fundo transparente
 $TempPngFile = imagecreatetruecolor(735, 620);
 $TransparentColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($TempPngFile, 0, 0, 0, 127);
 imagefill($TempPngFile, 0, 0, $TransparentColor);
 imagealphablending($TempPngFile, true);
 imagesavealpha($TempPngFile, true);
 #Abrindo imagem principal e fixando definições de transparência
 $img1 = imageCreateFromPng('assets/img/FrFUR0.png');
 imageAlphaBlending($img1, true);
 imageSaveAlpha($img1, true);
 #Abrindo moldura e forçando transparência
 $img2 = imageCreateFromPng('assets/img/FrFUR1.png');
 imageAlphaBlending($img2, true);
 imageSaveAlpha($img2, true);
 #Inserindo moldura e fixando posicionamento
 imagecopy($TempPngFile, $img1, 15, 15, 0, 0, imagesx($img1), imagesy($img1));
 imagecopy($TempPngFile, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2));
 #Salva imagem no servidor
 # imagepng($TempPngFile, 'assets/uploads/NewPng.png');
 #ou mostra imagem no navegador
 header("Content-type: image/png");
 imagepng($TempPngFile);
 #Destrói imagens
 imageDestroy($TempPngFile);
 imageDestroy($img1);
 imageDestroy($img2);
```

O resultado é esse aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Download: [Imagem principal](https://s29.postimg.org/tp8jfdqwn/FrFUR0.png).
Download: [Moldura](https://s29.postimg.org/tdr32magn/FrFUR1.png).

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!